# Android button drawing circle effect

Tags: android, android-studio

Hey guys I just wanna ask question about the default button in android studio when you click it it has effect that it draw circle and fills the button but i wanna know how i can do that in custom button ? thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new file "res/drawable/ripple_effect.xml" then add this as background for the button through XML or dynamically.

i.e. android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#f816a463"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f816a463" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Comment: It works thanks! but can you tell me how to resize effect to make it wider than the button ?I tried android : radius but didn't work

Comment: I am not really sure how to do it. As this is the background of a button so it won't go out of the button.

Comment: I was trying to do it with different methods finally it worked incase if anyone has a question about it .. . . . What I did was a trick it didn't really increase the size of the ripple effect but by using Android: padding  inside the attributes of the button . . . . When you increase it it increases the area of the effect by giving it space .